# Determine whether the Galois group of the polynomial $x^5-2$ over $\mathbb Q$ is cyclic or NOT

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

> Let , $G$ be a Galois group of the splitting field of $x^5-2$ over $\mathbb Q$. Then $G$ is **cyclic or NOT.**

**Attempt:**

Roots of the equation $x^5-2=0$ are $2^{1/5}$ , $2^{1/5}\xi$ , $2^{1/5}\xi^2$ , $2^{1/5}\xi^3$ , $2^{1/5}\xi^4$ , where , $\xi=e^{2\pi i/5}$.

So , the splitting field of the polynomial $x^5-2$ over $\mathbb Q$ is $\mathbb Q(2^{1/5},\xi)$. Now , $$\left|Gal\left(\mathbb Q(2^{1/5},\xi)/\mathbb Q\right)\right|=\left(\mathbb Q(2^{1/5},\xi):\mathbb Q\right)=5.4=20.$$

> 1. Now how we can show that this group is cyclic or NOT ?
> 2. Is it directly depend on $n$ and $a$ ? for the polynomial $x^n-a$.
> 3. I know the Galois group of the polynomial $x^n-1$ over $\mathbb Q$ is **abelian** , but I don't know about cyclic.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

1. An element of the Galois group can be faithfully identified by its action on the set of roots. Therefore we can view this Galois group as a subgroup of $S_5$. Are there elements of order $20$ in $S_5$?
2. Assuming that $a$ has no multiple prime factors you always get a cyclic group of order $n$ as the Galois group $Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\root n\of a,\zeta_n)/\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_n))$. This will be a normal subgroup of the Galois group of $x^n-a$  over the rationals. The argument is a bit longer, but it turns out that the Galois group is a semi-direct product, of order $n\phi(n)$, and never cyclic when $n>2$.
3. You probably also know that this Galois group is isomorphic to the group of units of modular integers, $\Bbb{Z}_n^*$. In an earlier course you have probably seen results telling for which choices of $n$ is this group cyclic?

Comment: Sorry about only giving a hint for the title question initially. I'm not sure about the role of part 2 in your question. My #2 hint is not really a hint at all. Looking for another thread where that has been covered, I'm fairly sure they exist...

Comment: @ Jyrki Lahtonen) I know that the order of the Galois group of the polynomial $x^n-a$ is $$\begin{cases}\phi(n) & \text{ for $a=1$ }\\n \phi(n) & \text{ for $a \not= 1$}\end{cases}$$. I want a condition on $n$ for which the group is cyclic.

Comment: In general you need a condition on $a$ as well. For example if $a$ is a perfect square and $n$ is even. Anyway, the argument from Gerry's answer extends to show that when $\phi(n)>1$ (i.e. $n>2$) the Galois group will not be abelian.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a couple of group elements, and see whether they commute. E.g., there's an automorphism $\sigma$ fixing $\root5\of2$, and taking $\xi$ to $\xi^2$, and there's another automorhism $\tau$ taking $\root5\of2$ to $\xi\root5\of2$, and fixing $\xi$. Do you get $\sigma\tau=\tau\sigma$?